# Encountered the symbol "=" in oracle apex

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to declare an if statement but i keep getting and error when my code seems to be perfectly fine.

```
    DECLARE    
    prole varchar2(64);
    result varchar2(8);

   begin

   prole :=APEX_UTIL.GET_SESSION_STATE('user_role');

   if prole:='employee' then 

   result:='44';

   elsif prole:='USER' then

   result:='28';

   end if;

   return result;
    end;
```

Comment: Remove the `:` and it should work.

Comment: if prole = 'employee'

Comment: For infor, you could write as: `result := case prole when 'employee' then '44' when 'USER' then '28' end;`

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE    
prole varchar2(64);
result varchar2(8);

begin

prole :=APEX_UTIL.GET_SESSION_STATE('user_role');

if prole='employee' then 

result:='44';

elsif prole='USER' then

result:='28';

end if;

return result;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

In PL/SQL, the assignment operator is `:=` and the equality operator is `=`. Don't mix them up!

By the way, you could do the whole thing with a `case` expression:

```
begin
    return
        case apex_util.get_session_state('user_role')
            when 'employee' then '44'
            when 'USER' then '28'
        end;
end;
```

Normally in PL/SQL, only a function can return something. I'm not familiar with Apex though so perhaps this is OK here.

Are your user roles really `'employee'` (lowercase) and `'USER'` (uppercase)? I would expect them to be consistent, for example `'EMPLOYEE'`/`'USER'` or `'employee'`/`user'`.

Are the result values really text strings (`'44'`, `'28'`) or are they numbers (`44`, `28`)?

Comment: the block of code will be called as a function in this case, apex will expect something to be returned.